# overflow:hidden + display:inline-block moves text upwards

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML:

```
<div>
    a<span style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">b</span>c
</div>
```

What I expect to see: `abc`.

What I see (in Chrome, Safari, Firefox): [image: abc]

`b` is higher than `a` and `c`. Why it is so and how to fix it?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This happens because the `inline-block` element has height equal to its parent and `overflow: hidden` causes its bottom edge to be aligned on the text baseline of the parent. As a result the space that is available for descenders on the text is essentially doubled for the `<span>` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bj8YL/23/)).

You can fix this by also giving it `vertical-align: bottom`.

Comment: But without `overflow:hidden` everything is OK

Comment: @Daniil: `overflow:hidden` changes the baseline for `inline-block` elements, and since the default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline` the element moves vertically. See the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) (scroll to the bottom).

Comment: It worked on the `inline-block` element. Thanks, dude.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer! I needed just this exact information for a oddly specific issue. It's fixed now!

Comment: I had this issue, but only on Firefox. Adding `vertical-align: bottom` fixed it on FF, but made it look farther down than it should have been on Safari and Chrome. The fix for this was to use `vertical-align: text-top` instead.