# CSS: combination of display:inline-block and overflow:hidden causes weird behavior?

Tags: html, css

So if I've got two sibling HTML elements like so:

```
<div>
  <span id="child-one">ChildOne</span>
  <span id="child-two">ChildTwo</span>
</div>
```

And one, but not both, of these two sibling elements have "display:inline-block" AND "overflow:hidden" in their styling:

```
#child-one {
  display: inline-block;
}

#child-two {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then one sibling is shown offset a small distance below the other.  (See it happening here: https://jsfiddle.net/reyan62/oqc71f25/) (P.S. I'm using Chrome)

Does anyone have an explanation for this?  It seems very odd.  I'm not super familiar with what "display:inline-block" does though.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, my bad, this is pretty clearly answered elsewhere on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `overflow: hidden;` on both elements. If it's not possible you can use `vertical-align` to address the issue. This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566710/overflowhidden-displayinline-block-moves-text-upwards) explains the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Add `div > span { vertical-align: top; }` to fix this.

Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/oqc71f25/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is the best guide I used to understand how inline-block works, I hope it helps you,

http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `overflow:hidden` on the both of them or you can align them manually.

You could also `position` your elements into the div.